# How to calculate the properties of the resultant 2D Gaussian from the deconvolution of one anisotropic, 2D Gaussian with another?

Tags: convolution, image-processing, gaussian, deconvolution

Anisotropic, two-dimensional Gaussians, are described by the equation (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function)):

$f(x,y)=A\exp \left( -(a(x-x_0)^2 + 2b(x-x_0)(y-y_0) + c(y-y_0)^2 )\right)$

where A is the amplitude of the peak, $x_0$ and $y_0$ are the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the peak, respectively, and:

$a=\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{2\sigma_{\rm maj}^2} + \frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{2\sigma_{\rm min}^2}$,
$b=-\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{4\sigma_{\rm maj}^2} + \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{4\sigma_{\rm min}^2}$,
$c=\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{2\sigma_{\rm maj}^2} + \frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{2\sigma_{\rm min}^2}$

where $\theta$ is the angle of clockwise rotation for the major axis from the $x$-axis, $\sigma_{\rm maj}$ is the standard deviation of the major axis and $\sigma_{\rm min}$ is the standard deviation of the minor axis.

Given two, 2-dimensional Gaussians, $F(x,y)$ and $G(x,y)$, their convolution yields another 2-dimensional Gaussian distribution, $H(x,y)$, i.e. $F*G=H$.

In the context of this question, the properties of G and H are both known, whereby they are both anisotropic, and $A_H \neq A_G, \theta_H \neq \theta_G, \sigma_{\rm maj,H} \neq \sigma_{\rm maj,G}, \sigma_{\rm min,H} \neq \sigma_{\rm min,G}$)

My question is this, how do I calculate $\theta_F, \sigma_{\rm maj,F}$, and $\sigma_{\rm min,F}$ ?

**Note**: In the case where $G(x,y)$ is isotropic (i.e. 'circular'), the solution is simply $\theta_{\rm F}=\theta_{\rm H}$, $\sigma_{\rm maj,F} = \sqrt{\sigma_{\rm maj,H}^2 - \sigma_{\rm G}^2}$, and $\sigma_{\rm min,F} = \sqrt{\sigma_{\rm min,H}^2 - \sigma_{\rm G}^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\eqalign{
  & a\left( {x - x_0 } \right)^2  + 2b\left( {x - x_0 } \right)\left( {y - y_0 } \right) + c\left( {y - y_0 } \right)^2  =   \cr 
  &  = \xi ^2  + {{2b} \over {\sqrt {ac} }}\xi \eta  + \eta ^2  =   \cr 
  &  = \xi ^2  + {{2b} \over {\sqrt {ac} }}\xi \eta  + {{b^2 } \over {ac}}\eta ^2  + \left( {1 - {{b^2 } \over {ac}}} \right)\eta ^2  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\xi  + {b \over {\sqrt {ac} }}\eta } \right)^2  + \left( {1 - {{b^2 } \over {ac}}} \right)\eta ^2  \cr} 
$$

You may want to apply matrix notation to the above ..

p.s.: do not forget the minus sugn in the $\exp$

Comment: Apologies, but I'm not even sure where to start!

Answer (score -1):

First 1D Gaussian

$e^{- a x^{2} - b x - c}$

Second 1D Gaussian

$e^{- a' x^{2} - b' x - c'}$

Their 1D convolution

$  \frac{\sqrt{\pi} e^{- a x^{2} - b x - c - c' + \frac{\left(2 a x + b - b'\right)^{2}}{4 \left(a + a'\right)}}}{\sqrt{a + a'}}$

Substitutions for making this 2D, following the convention from OP, hence the extra factor 2:

$ b=2\cdot b\cdot \tau$
$ c=c\cdot \tau^2$
$ b'=2\cdot b'\cdot (y-\tau)$
$ c'= c'\cdot (y-\tau)^2$

Result from these substitutions:

$ \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{a + a'}} \cdot e^{- a x^{2} - 2 b \tau x - c \tau^{2} - c' \left(- \tau + y\right)^{2} + \frac{\left(2 a x + 2 b \tau - 2 b' \left(- \tau + y\right)\right)^{2}}{4 \left(a + a'\right)}}$

Now convolve over $y$:

$ \pi \sqrt{- \frac{1}{- a c - a c' - a' c - a' c' + b^{2} + 2 b b' + b'^{2}}} \cdot \\
e^{\frac{x^{2} \left(- a a' c - a a' c' + a b'^{2} + a' b^{2}\right) + x y \left(- 2 a b' c - 2 a' b c' + 2 b^{2} b' + 2 b b'^{2}\right) + y^{2} \left(- a c c' - a' c c' + b^{2} c' + b'^{2} c\right)}{a c + a c' + a' c + a' c' - b^{2} - 2 b b' - b'^{2}}}$

I could also post the Python code (using Sympy) to reproduce this.